# Swap button image when state changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I am testing a change of button states however I am having several difficulties.

I am trying to set an image for the buttons when they are in a natural state (pause). When I click the button on a line, a dropdown opens and I want to click on start on that line, the button changes the image set in the Start state. My problem is that none of the images appear, does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Thank you!

**html**

```
<button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
    <img *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers.currentState === 'pause'" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcW6cJlI-KlS721hkuHDTMydZ_snrkhL9sm9wYHWRhd3FlvF1b&s">
    <img *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.id]?.currentState ==='start'"
    src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190516/original/pngtree-pause-vector-icon-png-image_3791321.jpg">
    <img *ngIf="!taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.id]?.currentState ==='start'"
    src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190516/original/pngtree-pause-vector-icon-png-image_3791321.jpg">
  </button>
        <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item"
                    *ngIf="!taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID] || taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID].currentState === 'pause'"
                    routerLinkActive="active" (click)="startTimer(data)">Start</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item"
                    *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState === 'start'" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="pauseTimer(data)">Stop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `button` section as follows,

I have also added `height` and `width` attribute for better viewing of image.

```html
<button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
    <img *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState === 'pause' || taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID] == undefined" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcW6cJlI-KlS721hkuHDTMydZ_snrkhL9sm9wYHWRhd3FlvF1b&s" width="50" height="50">
    <img *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState ==='start'"
    src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190516/original/pngtree-pause-vector-icon-png-image_3791321.jpg" width="50" height="50">
    <img *ngIf="!taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState ==='start'"
    src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190516/original/pngtree-pause-vector-icon-png-image_3791321.jpg" width="50" height="50">
</button>
```

Comment: In the case of the buttons worked, however in that user who does not have any time stamp, the button does not appear, in the remaining worked :(

Comment: what do you mean by timestamp? in what case its not working?

Comment: I put a picture in the post ... the user "Cristiano" ... does not have the button, for never had a start time :(

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check. added `|| taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID] == undefined` in `start`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Do you know how I can stop a timer when another one runs? I do not intend to run several simultaneously. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think that a logical part. You can check before starting any timer if any other time is already running. If thats the case, stop all existing timers and start requested timer.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I wanted, but I am having some problems applying. Not stopping correctly